# How to send audio file to server via POST request in Java (Android App)?

Tags: java, android

I want to send an audio file to a server via a POST request in my Java Android App. The following code is what I currently have, however, it is not working.

I have found this class implementing a MultiPart Utility:

```
public class MultipartUtility {

    private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private String charset;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private final String boundary;

    public MultipartUtility(String requestURL, String charset)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;

        // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";

        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CodeJava Agent");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Test", "Bonjour");
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
                true);
    }

    public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(
                LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }


    public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
            throws IOException {
        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
                        + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Type: "
                        + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }


    public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append(name + ": " + value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }


    public List<String> finish() throws IOException {
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.close();

        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }

        return response;
    }

}
```

and want to send a POST request to a server with this client code:

```
String requestURL = "http://0.0.0.0:5000/test";
        try {
            com.eng.elfarsisy.recored.MultipartUtility multipart = new com.eng.elfarsisy.recored.MultipartUtility(requestURL, charset);

            multipart.addHeaderField("User-Agent", "CodeJava");
            multipart.addHeaderField("Test-Header", "Header-Value");

            multipart.addFormField("description", "Cool Pictures");
            multipart.addFormField("keywords", "Java,upload,Spring");

            multipart.addFilePart("fileUpload", uploadFile1);

            List<String> response = multipart.finish();

            System.out.println("SERVER REPLIED:");

            for (String line : response) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
```

However I am getting this response:

`I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false`
`I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false`
`W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied`

How can I fix this? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added this permission to your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```